# How large is an issar coin in halacha?

Tags: shiurim-measurements, lulav-etrog-arba-minim

The Shulchan Aruch OC (648:2) [writes](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.648.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

> אתרוג שניקב נקב מפולש כל שהוא פסול ושאינו מפולש אם היה כאיסר פסול ואם
> חסר כל שהוא פסול ויש אומרים דגם בנקב מפולש בעינן חסרון משהו ושאינו
> מפולש בחסרון כאיסר - An etrog that has a puncture of any size that
> goes through its entirety is invalid. If it does not go through but is
> the size of an issar [coin], it is invalid. If it is missing any
> amount, it is invalid. Some say that with a puncture that goes through
> we require some to be missing and with one that does not go through we
> require it to be missing an issar's worth.

What is the halachic shiur/size of an issar coin nowadays?

**Note:** The Rambam Shekalim (1:3) [poskins](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Sheqel_Dues.1.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

> וּמִשְׁקַל הָאִיסָר אַרְבַּע שְׂעוֹרוֹת - the weight of an issar is
> four barley grains

Although I'm not sure if it's referring to the same coin, Wikipedia [says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biblical_and_Talmudic_units_of_measurement) in the section on Biblical coins:

> "Issar" (pl. issarim) - a Roman copper coin (As) - 177 mg (2.732 troy
> grains)

...but I don't know what that measure means today.

Comment: Seemingly this seeks an area not a weight. 177mg could cover any size area depending how thin it is.

Comment: I recall hearing that R Eliashiv paskened on the size of the Issar based on finds of ancient Issar coins, but I couldn't find it after a quick search. It might be on Havdalah rather than on Daled minim.

Comment: See also R Rimon in his sefer/pamphlet on Daled minim (p71) "we aren't expert in the size of an issar"

Comment: Are there any definitions to the shiur of a barley corn in halacha? If so, can we multiply that by four to give the area of an issar?